# issue loading image using facebook's Fresco image loading library when imagepath contains special chars like %

Tags: android, facebook, fresco, imageloader

I am using Fresco to load image in our app but in case where imagepath contains any special symbols or chars like % or #, it doesn't load image.

imagepath for my image is :
**/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/OGQ/Richard Walker_Stairway To Heaven%3F_YkFgR2RZ.jpg**
Fresco version: [1.5.0]
https://github.com/facebook/fresco/issues/1972
Any heap appreciated!

Comment: Not sure about Fresco , cant you go with glide ? https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Comment: @Stallion we have shifted from glide to fresco and finding it better in terms of memory management, performance, and image loading experience. Glide had the same issue as well https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/867 but its fixed and i tried the same with fresco, its working...so the solution is  load(Uri.fromFile(new File(...)) ..thanks

Comment: https://androidcreativity.wordpress.com/2017/04/22/compare-image-library/

Answer (score 0):

convert imagepath to Uri as :

```
Uri picUri= Uri.fromFile(new File("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/OGQ/Richard Walker_Stairway To Heaven%3F_YkFgR2RZ.jpg"

ImageRequest request=ImageRequestBuilder.newBuilderWithSource(picUri).setResizeOptions(new ResizeOptions(width, height)).build();
```

This will load image contains special chars or symbols.